# Is there a best suspension frame?

Tags: frames, full-suspension

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_suspension#Rear_suspension) Trek holds two of the several suspension frame designs, and uses them both (combined) on their [mountain bikes](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/mountain/gravity/slash/slash_7/#). The technologies are EVO link and Full Floater, being claimed to both reduce pedal bob and brake squat.

Does this mean that there exists a "most advanced" frame geometry for a suspension bike, and that it is being produced by Trek?

---

After a quick drop at the LBS:

- Trek patented only the name, many quality bikes use this geometry, which
- is indeed superior to traditional 4-link designs.

Comment: Sounds more like some marketing babble.

Comment: Idk. 1. it's on Wikipedia 2. it makes sense to patent a frame geometry, if it is very good. Holding a patent costs quite some $$

Comment: Patents aren't necessarily indicative of advanced technology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_troll

Comment: @Vorac see recent Wiki PR company issue: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/oct/22/wikipedia-ban-sock-puppet-pr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no, there is not a "a best suspension frame" (just as there is no best car, best breed of cat, or best person).

There are loads of different suspension designs (single pivot, FSR, DW Link, Maestro, VPP, URT, iDrive, ABP, Switch, Pathlink, Droplink, to name only a few), each with their own distinct advantages and disadvantages. There are also a lot of different types of bike, aimed at different types of riding. What works for World Cup cross country might not work for downhill racing, at RedBull Rampage or even on trail bikes. They all make a different set of compromises. There are also a lot of different people with different riding styles, priorities and preferences. There's so much more too add into the equation, too (sizing and geometry, cockpit, wheel size and so on).

So while there might be a best suspension frame design for a given rider on for a certain trail, there is no single suspension design that stands out above all others in all situations.

Have a read of http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/buyers-guide-to-mountain-bike-suspension-part-2-28438/ which provides a good primer on the topic.

Comment: But what prevents there existing an optimal suspension geometry, which can be scaled for different uses. E.g. Less travel, steaper headtube -> XC, more travel, slacker headtube etc. -> AM, etc.

Comment: @Vorac Theoretically, nothing. But look at an XC Trek and a DH Trek side by side: The suspension might use the same basic layout, but the linkages, pivot points, leverage ratios, shocks and so on are all very different because they're designed for very different tasks. Even if you conclude that it's same design across the entire range, what makes it "the best", when compared to a Specialized FSR, Santa Cruz VPP, Yeti Switch or Pivot DW Link design in all situations?

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at the discussions about trail on road forks. Even with a super specific and narrow component field there is no real conclusion as to what is "best." Some people like high trail, some like low trail, some like medium trail...and so on.